# How to test a service function in kotlin which uses a late init Id?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, testing

I am new to testing in kotlin and I was wondering how I can test this function:

this is my SegmentService file:

```
    fun createSegmentFromUserIds(userIds: List<String>, name:String, appId: String): Segmentation {
        val filter = createUserIdFilter(userIds)
        val createSegmentRequest =  CreateSegmentRequest(
            name = name, attribute = filter, type = SegmentType.STATIC
        )
        val segmentation = segmentMetaService.saveSegmentInfo(createSegmentRequest, appId)
        querySegmentService.runUpdateQuery(users = userIds, appId = appId, segmentId = segmentation.id)
        return segmentation
    }
```

this is the saveSegmentInfo function:

```
fun saveSegmentInfo(createSegmentFilter: CreateSegmentRequest, appId: String): Segmentation {
    val segmentInfo = segmentationRepository.save(createSegmentFilter.let {
        Segmentation(
            attribute = it.attribute, name = it.name, appId = appId, type = it.type
        )
    })
    logger.info("Segment info saved with id: ${segmentInfo.id}, name: ${segmentInfo.name}")
    return segmentInfo
}
```

and this is the Segmentation Document

```
@Document(Segmentation.COLLECTION_NAME)
class Segmentation(
@Field(ATTRIBUTE)
val attribute: Filter,

@Field(NAME)
val name: String,

@Indexed
@Field(APP_ID)
val appId: String,

@Field(STATUS)
var status: SegmentStatus = SegmentStatus.CREATED,

@Field(TYPE)
var type: SegmentType = SegmentType.STATIC,

@Field(USER_COUNT)
var userCount: Long? = null,
) {
    @Id
    lateinit var id: String

    @Field(CREATION_DATE)
    var creationDate: Date = Date()
}
```

I have written this test for it:

```
class SegmentServiceTest {
    private val segmentMetaService = mock(SegmentMetaService::class.java)
    private val querySegmentService = mock(QuerySegmentService::class.java)
    private val converterService = mock(ConverterService::class.java)
    private val userAttributeService = mock(UserAttributeService::class.java)
    private val segmentConsumerUserInfoProducer = mock(SegmentConsumerUsersInfoProducer::class.java)
    private val segmentationRepository = mock(SegmentationRepository::class.java)
    @Test
    fun `createSegmentFromUserIds should create a new segment`() {
        val segmentService = SegmentService(
            segmentMetaService = segmentMetaService,
            querySegmentService = querySegmentService,
            converterService = converterService,
            userAttributeService = userAttributeService,
            segmentConsumerUserInfoProducer = segmentConsumerUserInfoProducer
        )


        val userIds = listOf("user-1", "user-2", "user-3")
        val filter = AndFilter(
            operations = listOf(
                AndFilter(
                    operations = listOf(
                        StringListContainsFilter(
                            field = "userId", operationType = StringQueryOperationType.IN, values = userIds
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        val createSegmentRequest = CreateSegmentRequest(
            name = "segment-name", attribute = filter, type = SegmentType.STATIC
        )
        val segment = Segmentation(attribute = filter, name = "segment-name", type = SegmentType.STATIC, appId = "app-id" )
        `when`(segmentationRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(segment)


        `when`(segmentMetaService.saveSegmentInfo(createSegmentRequest, "app-id")).thenReturn(segment)
        val createdSegment = segmentService.createSegmentFromUserIds(userIds = userIds, name = "segment-name", appId = "app-id")
        assertEquals(segment, createdSegment)
    }
}
```

but I am facing this error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property id has not been initialized
```

So what am I doing wrong here?
How can I initialize the Id? or should I refactor my code so for it to become testable?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mocking / providing the answers to the wrong calls.

1. you mock `segmentationRepository.save(..)` but this call won't ever be made since that call is inside `segmentMetaService.saveSegmentInfo(...)` which is mocked so the real code is not called.
2. when you call `segmentService.createSegmentFromUserIds(..)`, my guess (stack trace would be useful on the error, BTW), is that this method proceeds passed the invocation of `segmentMetaService.saveSegmentInfo(...)` but in the next line you call `querySegmentService.runUpdateQuery(users = userIds, appId = appId, segmentId = segmentation.id)` which is accessing the uninitialised `id`.

The fix will be to set the `segment.id` when you set up the object for the answer to `segmentMetaService.saveSegmentInfo(..)`